# How can I convert a local time machine backup to a network accessible backup?

Tags: time-machine

I have a disk that I was using to locally backup my MBP to. I now have a Mac mini, and would like to share the disk over SMB so I can back up the MBP over the network. I have already tried plugging in the disk and sharing it over the network, but the permissions are locked to the disk, and even when accessing it over the network on the MBP it is permissioned to, it will not allow me to backup over the network. Any ideas?

Comment: It should be possible to create a disk image (sparsebundle) of your TM disk, then share the folder containing it over the network. Though I really wouldn't recommend it, you'd likely be better off creating a fresh backup and using the offline disk as a second backup.